# Limit the number of Active Directory connections while doing requests

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a script to check backup folders for those who are linked to users or computers that are not in the Active Directory.

```
# Gets the list of folders on the backup Server
$FolderList = Get-ChildItem $Server | select name

foreach ($Folder in $FolderList){

    # On each folder, gets the computer name and the user shortname (the backup folder are built using %COMPUTERNAME%-%USERNAME%)
    $Splited = $Folder.Name.Split("-")
    $ComputerName = $Splited[0]
    $ShortName = $Splited[1]
    $LastWrittenDate = Get-Item "$($Server)\$($Folder.Name)" | Select-Object LastWriteTime

    # Checks if the username exists in the Active Directory
    try{
        Get-ADUser $ShortName | Out-Null
    } catch {
        # If it doesn't exists, write in the user output file
        Add-Content "$($outputFile)_user.txt" "$($ShortName); $($LastWrittenDate.LastWriteTime)"
    }


    # Checks if the computer name exists in the Active Directory and the computer is not in the Active Directory
    try {
        Get-ADComputer $ComputerName | Out-Null
    } catch {
        # If it doesn't exists, write in the computer output file
        Add-Content "$($outputFile)_computers.txt" "$($ComputerName); $($LastWrittenDate.LastWriteTime)"
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I make my request to check if the user/computer is in the AD, it opens a new connection to the AD and doesn't close it (the problem was detected when the logs files exploded).

Is there a way to open only one session to the AD and call all my request during that session?

Comment: "when the logs files exploded" - which log files?

Comment: The ones log files from our monitoring software. There was a lot of logon request and  no logoff

Comment: That doesn't necessarily imply that the connection is "new". The underlying connection may be reused even though powershell authenticates on every ldap query

Comment: The logs show thousands of events : "An account was successfully logged on".  I tried to connect to the AD using cd AD: , but while I'm in it Iose the access to my servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications on my script and the monitoring logs don't show mass logon request.

```
$FolderList = Get-ChildItem $Server | select name
# I log onto the AD and execute my requests
cd AD:
foreach ($Folder in $FolderList){
```

Then once I'm done on one server, I go back on my D drive and start again on the next one.
I have to log in and out between each connection to the server because I cannot access my servers once connected to the AD (I can access my local drive though and write my output files).

Now I'm only making one logon request to the AD per server instead of one per file.